# Как вытащить анимацию в js из css!

Tags: javascript, css, jquery, gif

Вот, поправил. Но все равно не работает, не выводится gif при отправке данных

```js
$.ajax({
        url: "assets/ajax/mail.php",
        type: "POST",
        dataType : "json",
        cache: false,
        contentType: false,
        processData: false,
        data: formData, //указываем что отправляем
        beforeSend: function () {
            $("#sendMail").prop("disable", true);
            $("_sending").show();
        },
        success: function(data){
            $("#form_contact").trigger("reset");
            console.log(data);

        }
    });
```

```css
.comment-form {
  position: relative;
}

.comment-form::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: rgba(51, 51, 51, 0.9) url(loading.gif) center / 50px no-repeat;
  opacity: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
  transition: all 0.5s ease 0s;
}

.comment-form._sending::after {
  opacity: 1;
  visibility: visible;
}
```

Нужно реализовать анимацию при отправке ajax отправки.
В css прописал gif файл и скрыл. Пытаюсь открыть при отправке ajax запроса. Но не выходит! Как обратится к гивке из css что бы js включил ее.

Спасибо!

```js
    //отправляем через ajax
    $.ajax({
        url: "assets/ajax/mail.php",
        type: "POST",
        dataType : "json",
        cache: false,
        contentType: false,
        processData: false,
        data: formData, //указываем что отправляем
        beforeSend: function () {
            $("#sendMail").prop("disable", true);
            $("#_sending").hide();
        },
        success: function(data){
            $("#form_contact").trigger("reset");
            console.log(data);

        }
    });

    return false;
});
```

```css
.comment-form {
  position: relative;
}

.comment-form::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: rgba(51, 51, 51, 0.9) url(loading.gif) center / 50px no-repeat;
  opacity: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
  transition: all 0.5s ease 0s;
}

.comment-form._sending::after {
  opacity: 1;
  visibility: visible;
}
```

Comment: вы внимательно посмотрите на свои селекторы

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, А заголовок вопроса так заинтриговал)

Comment: Если сделаете воспроизводимый JS, то уж с CSS можно разобраться будет легко.

Answer (score 0):

Короче, эта тема не работает с псевдоклассами. Ток с классами.

Comment: ::after и ::before это не псевдоклассы, а псевдоэлементы.
Вашу задачу можно решить с псевдоэлементами и даже с псевдоклассами (:active, :hover).
Просто детальнее изучите CSS